# Mongoose find returns different to client find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of trees,

```
type : String,
_id: String
geometry : {
    type : String,
    coordinates : {
        lng : Number,
        lat : Number
    }
},
properties : {
    name : String,
    id : String,
    featured : String,
    uniquename : String,
    latinname : String,
    siteid : String,
    introduction : String,
    description : String,
    numberOfImages : String,
    treeNumber : Number
}
```

If I use the mongo client and run db.trees.find() it works perfectly.

If I call run the http request;

```
app.get('/trees', function(req, res, next) {
Tree.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send(products);
});
});
```

The resulting JSON objects missing the geometry object and all of it's children.

How can I get the same result using the mongoose client as I do with the mongo client?

Output from mongo client

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa6635defda1f8cf7c098bd"),
"type" : "Feature",
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : {
        "lng" : 1.16195732,
        "lat" : 54.185463
    }
},
"properties" : {
    "name" : "Beech",
    "id" : "009b6a90-bc05-4e8e-958b-f8fb2fe5504a",
    "featured" : "0",
    "uniquename" : "Beech",
    "latinname" : "Fagus sylvatica",
    "siteid" : "fa3b443c-bd48-4585-804d-b00e4af15747",
    "introduction" : "",
    "description" : "NULL",
    "numberOfImages" : "0",
    "treeNumber" : 232
}
```

}

Output from mongoose

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "name": "Common ash",
    "id": "ff8fb641-42d1-4251-99b0-e47b2507ef88",
    "featured": "0",
    "uniquename": "Common ash",
    "latinname": "Fraxinus excelsior",
    "siteid": "fa3b443c-bd48-4585-804d-b00e4af15747",
    "introduction": "",
    "description": "NULL",
    "numberOfImages": "0",
    "treeNumber": 382
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question to show us a document from mongo shell command `db.trees.findOne().pretty()` and a single document from the mongoose query?

Comment: @chridam I've added what I can, the .pretty() method didn't work